# Console logs only show up once in React Native

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to get the hang of react native with a very simple app which will log how many times I press a button. Here's my code and my output.

Code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button} from 'react-native';

let numOfTimesPressed1 = 0;
let numOfTimesPressed2 = 0;

function printTimesPressed(num) {
  if (num == 1) {
    numOfTimesPressed1 += 1;
    console.log("Log In Button was pressed " + numOfTimesPressed1 + ".");
  } else {
    numOfTimesPressed2 += 1;
    console.log("Log In Button was pressed " + numOfTimesPressed2 + ".");
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Page Master</Text>
        <Button
          title="Log In"
          onPress={printTimesPressed(1)}
          >
        </Button>
        <Button
          title="Sign Up"
          onPress={printTimesPressed(2)}
          >
        </Button>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default HomeScreen;
```

Here's my output after I've hit both buttons multiple times:

```
 LOG  Running "PageMaster" with {"rootTag":1}
 LOG  Log In Button was pressed 1.
 LOG  Log In Button was pressed 1.
```

Why won't it update?

Answer (score 1):

`onPress` expects a function to be passed. Your code passes not a function but a result of calling `printTimesPressed(1)`, which is undefined

```
onPress={printTimesPressed(1)} // wrong: printTimesPressed(1) is not a function but a code that returns nothing
```

What you want is this

```
onPress={() => printTimesPressed(1)} // () => printTimesPressed(1) is a function

onPress={function() { printTimesPressed(1) }} // same thing
```

now `onPress` receives anonymous arrow function that will, when executed (when button is pressed), call `printTimesPressed` with respective argument

Comment: Thank you this makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

This happens because functions, on which React is based, are stateless. This is a specialty of functional programming. That means, functions cannot count, and will always act exactly the same when passing the exact same param. You will have to save your number elsewhere (e.g. in a state) to count how often a function is called. Here, you can find an example of a React Counter Button: https://wsvincent.com/react-counter/

Comment: Functional programming is just a way to write a program. React is not based on functional or any other kind of programming. You are free to write any functions you want. In author's example function clearly can count as it performs side effects of updating external value

Answer (score 0):

First of all,
Please declare the variables and functions in class and try to use latest ECMAScript (ES).
here is the updated code according to standards, the main issue was the onPress handling, as you are trying using an older ES version it was causing issues and lastly in case of one class export that class directly

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';

export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  numOfTimesPressed1 = 0;
  numOfTimesPressed2 = 0;
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Button title="Log In" onPress={()=>this.printTimesPressed(1)} />
        <Button title="Sign Up" onPress={()=>this.printTimesPressed(2)} />
      </View>
    );
  }
  printTimesPressed = (num) => {
    if (num == 1) {
      this.numOfTimesPressed1 += 1;
      console.log('Log In Button was pressed ' + this.numOfTimesPressed1 + '.');
    } else if (num == 2) {
      this.numOfTimesPressed2 += 1;
      console.log('Sign up Button was pressed ' + this.numOfTimesPressed2 + '.');
    }
  }
}
```